# PDO statement not inserting

Tags: php, pdo

Is there any reason this PDO insert statement isn't inserting in MySQL?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO training courseId = :postCourse, title = :postCourseName, startDate = :postStartDate, endDate = :postEndDate");
$stmt->bindParam(':postCourse', $postCourse);
$stmt->bindParam(':postCourseName', $postCourseName);
$stmt->bindParam(':postStartDate', $postStartDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':postEndDate', $postEndDate);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm not getting any errors. Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Wrong SQL INSERT syntax. It should be something like this: `INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (:val1, :val2 ...)`

Comment: @bfavaretto incorrect, yes, wrong, questionable... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO training (courseId, title, startDate, endDate) VALUES
(:postCourse, :postCourseName, :postStartDate, :postEndDate);
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO training 
SET courseId = :postCourse, 
    title = :postCourseName,
    startDate = :postStartDate, 
    endDate = :postEndDate
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

You should be able to check for errors like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(...);
if (!$stmt) {
    var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Or:

```
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
```

Or:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
...
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're missing `SET`:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO training SET courseId = :postCourse, title = :postCourseName, startDate = :postStartDate, endDate = :postEndDate");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO training (courseId, title, startDate, endDate) VALUES (:postCourse, :postCourseName, :postStartDate, :postEndDate");
```

Check your INSERT syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html